# Vue.js + Materialize.js issue with select input reactivity

Tags: select, vue.js, materialize

I have this code with two forms.
The first form has a text input field for adding group names.

```
<form v-on:submit.prevent='addGroup'>
    <div class='input-field'>
        <label>Name</label>
        <input type='text' v-model='group_name'>
    </div>
```

As the code shows, on the form submit the function **addGroup** will be executed:

```
<script>
    const vm = new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        data: {
            group_name: '',
            groups: []
        },
        methods: {
            addGroup() {
                this.groups.push(this.group_name);
                this.group_name= '';
            }
        }
    });
</script>
```

The function **addGroup** only pushes the name from the text input to the groups Array.

The second form has a select field that should be updated by the values in the groups Array:

```
<select>
    <option v-for='group in groups'>{{ group }}</option>
</select>
```

This works without Materialize, but when I add Materialize to style the select field:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    M.FormSelect.init(document.querySelectorAll('select'));
});
```

Materialize is not only styling the select input, it is turning it into a <ul>. And this prevents the values added to groups from apearing in the select options.

Does anyone knows a way around this?

Comment: You're going to need to make a [wrapper component](https://vuejs.org/v2/examples/select2.html) to apply Materialize to the select at `mounted` time.

Comment: RoyJ how would I do that? I'm new to Vue.js

Comment: Looks like it's a tricky situation. Maybe [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43728599/392102)  will help.